# QDir::match() returns unexpected result

Tags: c++, qt

The following expression is returning false:

```
bool m = QDir::match("*.exe","path/file.exe");
```

Why? It should return true.

Comment: *if the **fileName** matches the wildcard* - a file name, not a path.

Comment: Yes, it matches the file name but not the path. Why? In Qt 5.1 it matched the path. Now I am using Qt 5.15 and it stopped working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works in Qt 6.5.1 (don't have anything older; sorry):

```
bool m = QDir::match("*/*.exe","path/file.exe");
```

So does:

```
bool m = QDir::match("path/*.exe","path/file.exe");
```

I'd recommend, though, that you familiarize yourself with [QFileInfo](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfileinfo.html) and use QT-native objects for holding your file/path strings.